# What is the difference between creating a new table or a materialized view in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Why would you create a materialized view vs. creating a new table? Is there a difference?

As I understand it incremental views get updated when the underlying data changes, but is there anything "extra" that you get from materialized views as compared to a table?

Comment: A new table is a denormalization, a views is not. Generally denormalization is a bad thing

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you already noticed in your question, the fact that a Materialized View (MV) is updated regularly respectively when the underlying data changes already *is* something extra/different that you get compared to creating another table hat holds the same data. Since you are not copying data (which would then be reduntant), you don't need to take care of keeping multiple copies in sync / up to date.

You can also use MV's for fast retrieval of *joins* or *aggregate data*, that are pre-computed and stored and, again, kept in sync with the underlying table data.

In SQL Server, the concept closest to Materialized Views is are *Indexed Views*. There is a number of constraints that need to be satisfied if you want to create an Indexed View, see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15). Indexed Views are updated automatically, no maintenance needed.

Comment: Ah, I see... materialized views **do** update on a regular basis?

Comment: What happens when I make a change to the upstream data? Does the full table get recalculated?

Comment: AFAIK, _Indexed Views_ (whic are the equivalent of materialized vies in MS SQL Server) are updated automatically, no maintenance needed.

Comment: Indexed views are not completely recalculated, in general, when you update a source table.  They are incrementally maintained.   For a trivial view of select <all cols> from T, an insert of one row in the base table also inserts one row in the view.  With group by + aggregates or joins, it will do the minimum work to incrementally maintain the indexed view.

Comment: @Mycchaka_Kleinbort "materialized views do update on a regular basis"... NO... Materialized views does not exists in MS SQL Server. SQL Server uses only Indexed views that are always synchronized, about data, to the source table. When any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE is done in source tables, the Indexed views is also modified at the data level, before the transaction ends, excatly like an index, and it is the reason why they are called Indexed Views not Materialized View like Oracle...

Answer (score 1):

Pros of Materialized View over Normal Table

- Performant
- Updated automatically
- Database Normalization
- Less to No maintenance overhead

The cons part is: Materialized View cannot be implemented with the base table which are very frequently updated., Technically we can but it's the worst practice because it gives storage/size issue.